# Get Data from batch iterable

Tags: apex, batch, class, global-methods, iteration

Good day everyone,

Maybe this question is basic for everyone but I'm having a problem with it, so I'm asking for help. I have created a `BATCH ITERABLE` .

```
global with sharing class batchProcessor implements Database.batchable<String>, Database.Stateful
{
global Iterable<String> start(Database.batchableContext batchableContext)
   { 
     // m_csvFile is blob data in csv file
       return new CSVIterator(m_csvFile.toString(), Parser.crlf);
   }
   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext, List<String> scope)  
   {
      // I want to get the first row of the csv or the header for mapping
      System.debug(scope[0]);
   }
}
```

This is also my CSVIterator.class

```
global with sharing class CSVIterator implements Iterator<String>, Iterable<String>
{
   private String m_CSVData;
   private String m_introValue;
   public CSVIterator(String fileData, String introValue)
   {
      m_CSVData = fileData;
      m_introValue = introValue; 
   }
   global Boolean hasNext()
   {
      return m_CSVData.length() > 1 ? true : false;
   }
   global String next()
   {
      String row = m_CSVData.subString(0, m_CSVData.indexOf(m_introValue));
      m_CSVData = m_CSVData.subString(m_CSVData.indexOf(m_introValue) + m_introValue.length(),m_CSVData.length());
      return row;
   }
   global Iterator<String> Iterator()
   {
      return this;   
   }
}
```

What i want to get at the moment is the first row of the iterable which is the csv header. As you've seen in my batch class i try to System.debug the scope[0] but the result is not the csv header ? How will i do it ?

Pls help.

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execute` method will be called multiple times with the next batch of rows so you need to grab the first row on the first call to the `execute`. Because you have the marker interface `Database.Stateful`, any fields you add to the class will then be preserved between batches:

```
public with sharing class batchProcessor implements
        Database.Batchable<String>, Database.Stateful {
    ...
    // Will be preserved between execute calls
    private String[] headings;
    ...
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<String> scope) {
        // If variable is null it's the first batch
        if (headings == null) {
            headings = scope[0].split(',');
        }
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that the code no longer needs to be `global` and `public` is usually the appropriate choice.

Comment: What a very simple answer for the question that give give me headache. Thank you so much. I've tried it and its working. You're the man.

Comment: By the way what if i tried to check if I am in the first row of the next batch.  I've tried to add another variable and then add an else statement where i initialize that variable but it is not working. I also want this because I only want to escape the first row of the first batch and nothing more. Pls help. Thanks...

Comment: @Hope Your batchable should work with varying batch sizes so doing something on the first row of the next batch seems wrong to me. But maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do. Probably best if you post a new question with your current code.

Comment: Sorry to bother you.But I encounter some problem with this one. I've tried to read 220 rows of csv and what I've notice is that when there is an error in the first 200 which the default number of batch, the header will get data from row 201.Why is that ? please help.

Comment: @Hope Do you mean that row 201 is used as the header for the second batch? If so I can imagine that the first batch failing doesn't result in the state information of the class - its headings field - being preserved as the transaction for the first batch is rolled back. But I can't think of a solution - I suggest you post a new question about that scenario to see if anyone has a solution.

Comment: It only happens when there are problem in the first batch. I dont know why. But if there is no problem with the data, all will be working well. Actually I've already asked new question in this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93739/efficient-way-to-get-the-first-data-in-batch-process-iteration

Comment: @Hope Right, but when there is a problem with the data the database rollback means the headings are not saved.